# Deriving predicted probabilities from gologit2 (proportional odds models) output

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, stata, ordinal-data

I am trying to understand the output from Richard Williams's amazing gologit2 STATA package. The software is used for ordinal logistic regression and circumvents violations of the proportional odds assumption by way of using generalized ordinal logistic regression and partial odds regression. A powerpoint to Williams's powerpoint presenting an overview of the package is provided here https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/gologit2/NASUG2005.ppt and additional information on the topic is given on his website: https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/gologit2/index.html

I am having issues understanding how to transform the regression output into probabilities for each outcome. In the image below (which comes from slide 19 of the powerpoint), Williams gives output from a partial odds model.

[image: Example of gologit2 output]

In trying to back-calculate the predicted probabilities of the SD and D outcome, for a 2 year old at otherwise baseline values, I keep getting negative probabilities. Here is an example:

P(SD for a 2 year old at baseline values) = expit(2.12173 + 2*-0.0216325)) = 0.889

P(D for a 2 year old at baseline values) = expit(0.6021625 + 2*-0.0216325)) - expit(2.12173 + 2*-0.0216325)) = 0.636 - 0.889 = -0.253

Am I doing something wrong? I am relatively new to ordinal logistic regression, but negative probabilities seem quite wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the option part of the command, you need to add the or option for odds ratios. the proportional odds model gives you odds ratios and not probabilities.